# Hyperlinks to pagenote go to beginning of notes section rather than to note

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, memoir, pagenote

Hyperlinks generated with `\ref{note}` link to the beginning of the pagenote section rather than to the actual note, the way a `\ref` to a `\footnote` works. The hyperlink generated by `\pagenote` itself works fine. Is that a known problem? Is there a workaround?

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{hyperref,blindtext}

\begin{document}
\makepagenote

Hyperlink to \ref{note3} goes to beginning of notes section instead of to note \ref{note3}.

\blindtext\pagenote{\label{note1}\blindtext\par\blindtext}

\blindtext\pagenote{\label{note2}\blindtext\par\blindtext}

\blindtext\pagenote{\label{note3}\blindtext}


\printpagenotes
\end{document}
```

EDIT: Someone posted this answer but it's now gone, so I'll record it here: the workaround is to insert `\phantomsection` before the `\label` command.

Comment: I'll come back to this later on -- with `\notebackref` in the preamble, the `\pagenote` generates labels automatically such as `pagenote1-1` etc, but it is difficult to remember this

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a `memoir` error. Try the following in the preamble.

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\startnoteentrystart[4]{%
  \prenoteinnotes%
  \noteidinnotes{#1}{#2}%
  \@ifmtarg{#2}{\phantomsection\def\@currentlabel{#1}}{}%
  \pagenoteanchor{#4}%
  \pageinnotes{#3}%
  \prenotetext%
}
\makeatother
```

I added the `\phantomsection`

Answer (score 0):

You need another counter to use `\refstepcounter` INSIDE the note.  Interestingly, `\thepagenote` is 0 for all the notes.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{hyperref,blindtext}

\newcounter{mypagenote}

\newcommand{\notelink}[1]% #1=label
{\refstepcounter{mypagenote}\label{#1}}

\begin{document}
\makepagenote

Hyperlink to \ref{note3} goes to beginning of the third note.

\blindtext\pagenote{\notelink{note1}\blindtext\par\blindtext\par}

\blindtext\pagenote{\notelink{note2}\blindtext\par\blindtext}

\blindtext\pagenote{\notelink{note3}\blindtext}


\printpagenotes
\end{document}
```